# How to keep app running after log out of Terminal Services?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-terminal-services

I am trying to launch an application on a Windows 2003 server via logging into it remotely from my Windows 7 machine.  When I log off of the server, I notice that it closes the application as well.  Is there a way I can configure the server to keep my app running after I log out of the server?

p.s.  It is a GUI app and I have tried to configure it as a service but that isn't working as intended.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't get it to work as a service, just disconnect from the RDP sessions instead of logging out.

"Logging Off" versus "Disconnecting" from remote desktop sessions

http://metrix.fcny.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2788

Comment: Make sure the server is configured to not close disconnected sessions faster than you'd like to reconnect.

Comment: Well in this case, the app should run unmonitored for weeks.  And since the server is set up to only allow 2 remote connections, leaving one in a disconnected state could fill up the allowable limit of remote sessions.